# Asynchronous JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous

If I have:

```
fetched_user.settings = null;
fetched_user.settings = JSON.stringify(settings);
$http.post('/api_endpoint', {
  val: fetched_user.settings
});
```

And `JSON.stringify` takes forever to execute, then my understanding is `val: fetched_user.settings` will likely be null since this is executed asynchronously (async newbie checkpoint: is this correct?).

Normally in these situations I would supply a callback function to be executed on completion of the long-running task, however, JSON.stringify() doesn't provide the option for a callback.

How should I write this?

Comment: Why would you want it to be async?  Are user setting that big?

Comment: If you want it to be async, use web workers or `setTimeout`.

Comment: Nope, settings aren't big right now. But if it were async and I relied on the fact that it executed quickly while small, then should it ever take much longer to execute it would be a tricky bug to track down.

Comment: Async APIs usually either have a callback function passed as a parameter, or return a Promise. In either case, they wouldn't have a value ever directly available via the function return. So, it wouldn't work only some times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON.stringify is not asynchronous so the $http.post line won't execute until stringification is done.